# OpenGL graphical glitches

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl

Whenever build and run this piece of code in Xcode 5, with of the respective library computer display bugs out. It is hard to se but you can see that the window is appearing with the triangle.

Not sure if this makes a difference but I am running on OSX 1.9.2

`#include <iostream>

#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <OpenAL/al.h>
#include <OpenAL/alc.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>

int windowwitch= 1280;
int wndowhight=800;


using namespace std;
void display();

int main(int argc, char ** argv){

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);

    glutInitWindowSize(windowwitch, wndowhight);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GL_RGBA12 | GLUT_DOUBLE |GLUT_DEPTH);

    glutCreateWindow("Alex's Game!!");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);



    //Main loop
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}



void display(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT| GL_DEPTH_BITS);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

    glVertex2f(-2, -2);
    glVertex2f(0, 1);
    glVertex2f(1,-1);

    glEnd();



    glutSwapBuffers();
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GL_RGBA12 | GLUT_DOUBLE |GLUT_DEPTH);
                    ^^^^^^^^^
```

`GL_RGBA12` is not a valid argument for [`glutInitDisplayMode()`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node12.html).

Use `GLUT_RGBA` or `GLUT_RGB` instead.

---

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT| GL_DEPTH_BITS);
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`GL_DEPTH_BITS` is not a valid argument for [`glClear()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glClear.xml).

Use `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT` instead.